# Erro de exceção em Lista dinamica C ++

Tags: c++, lista, exceção

Estou criando uma lista encadeada em C++ e na condição `if (j ->n == x)`, no método `wasVisited` que deve checar se um elemento já foi inserido na lista, aparece a seguinte mensagem quando eu compilo:

> Exceção lançada: violação de acesso de leitura.
>   j era 0xCCCCCC.

Não consigo resolver, alguém pode me ajudar? Estou usando o visualStudio como IDE.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Celula{

public:
    int n;
    Celula* prox;

    Celula() {

        n = -1;
        prox = NULL;

    }//fim Construtor

    Celula(int x) {

        n = x;
        prox = NULL;

    }//fim construotor
};
class Lista {

public:
    Celula* origem;
    Celula* fim;

    Lista() {

        Celula x;
        origem = &x;
        fim = &x;

    }//fim construtor

    void inserir(int x) {

        Celula c(x);


        fim->prox = fim = &c;

    }//fim inserir

    bool wasVisited(int x) {

        bool res = false;
        Celula* j = origem->prox;

        do {

            if (j ->n == x) {

                res = true;

            }//fim if

            else {

                j = j->prox;


            }//fim else

        } while (res == false && j != NULL);//fim do.while

        return res;

    }//fim wasVisited


};

int main()
{
    Lista teste;

    teste.inserir(2);
    teste.wasVisited(2);
    teste.wasVisited(1);
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ele já está sendo iniciado: "Celula* j = origem->prox;"

o erro que está dando é na hora de comparar o valor do elemento do objeto que o ponteiro j aponta com o valor 'x' enviado como parametro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está aqui

```
Celula x;
```

O valor de x no construtor, é perdido ao sair da função pois é uma variável local. Com isso `origem` e `fim` se tornam valores não inicializados gerando acesso á 0xCCCCCC. para resolver isso basta alterar a construção:

```
Lista() {

   Celula *x = new Celula();
   origem = x;
   fim = x;

}
```

Comment: Deu certo, teve uns erros a mais, porem tranquilos de resolver, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, bons estudos

Comment: `new` não deveria ser usado em código normal, nunca, apenas quando é realmente a última ferramenta que resta. `std::unique_ptr` e os outros ponteiros inteligentes deveriam ser as primeiras ferramentas a serem consideradas.